# how to select the rows where distinct col1 and empty col2

Tags: mysql, sql

**My table:**

```
// mytable
+-----+----------+--------------+
| id  |  number  |     name     |
+-----+----------+--------------+
|  1  |    1     |    red       |
|  2  |    1     |              |
|  3  |    1     |              |
|  4  |    2     |    blue      |
|  5  |    2     |              |
|  6  |    3     |              |
|  7  |    3     |              |
|  8  |    3     |              |
|  9  |    4     |              |
|  10 |    4     |              |
+-----+----------+--------------+
```

Now I want this output: `id=6` and `id=9`. *(distinct number and name is empty)* something like this:

```
// mynewtable
+-----+----------+--------------+
| id  |  number  |     name     |
+-----+----------+--------------+
|  6  |    3     |              |
|  9  |    4     |              |
+-----+----------+--------------+
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable group by number where name='' order by id ASC;
```

**My error:**

> **Warning:** mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in {addres} on line {x}

how can I fix it ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no no, I have not the number of `id`, I meant that I want this output: `id=6`, `id=9`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Suppose there is no ID column, then how can I select Sixth row and Ninth row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work well, self tested!

```
SELECT id, number 
FROM `table` 
WHERE name='' and number not in(select number from `table` where name !='') 
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY id
```

**point:** if the number of the rows is too much (in reality), you should use *index*  for them.

Comment: Ah, why do you think that ? `while(1)` is Infinite, but this query end with results as expected!

Comment: you right, your query worked, but just on fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5b57b/1/0) ! on my real database, it won't work, and really I don't know why !!!

Comment: ok, tell me what is my problem ?! why I can't use it ? I replace my real column name with yours, and also table name, but still it won't work ...

Comment: It's working well on fiddle too, not sure why not works at your end .. see [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7rcv61dcmf9ha3/Screenshot%202015-07-03%2022.39.14.png?dl=0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82324/discussion-between-kamal-pal-and-stack).

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa, there was a little mistake in my code :

```
SELECT 
    MIN(t.id),
    t.number,
    "" as name
FROM 
(SELECT 
    id, 
    number,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN name <> "" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS count_not_empty
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY number) AS t
WHERE t.count_not_empty =0
GROUP BY t.number
```

See sqlfiddle (old output) : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eda7/6/0
See new sqlfiddle (new output asked) : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eda7/12/0

If there's a mistake, I would advise you to look if you are well connected to your database. You could try something like :

```
$result = mysql_query(" you query here ");
if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

If it "echo" an error, give us the error so that we can find a solution.

Comment: @stack : I edited, you can test on sqlfiddle. If you still have an error, look if the problem does not come from something else than the query (like your PDO Statement if you are using PHP).

Comment: please check out my edit ... (editing my output table)

Comment: Well that's easy you just add t.number, "" as name  in the first SELECT. It gives somthing like SELECT MIN(t.id), t.number, "" as name FROM [...]. I'll edit my main answer and the sqlfiddle. Note that I used "" as name directly since we already know that they all have an empty name.

Answer (score 0):

As

- you commented the **id** column not to exist, and
- from the data perspective any out of the rows (6, 7, 8) and (9, 10) respectively should be good,

one the following might work for you (depending on whether you actually have to check against empty strings or **NULL**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  number
  , MAX(name) AS name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY number
HAVING MAX(name) IS NULL
;   

SELECT DISTINCT
  number
  , MAX(name) AS name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY number
HAVING MAX(name) = ''
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42688/1)
As it requires no sub-selects, it might provide a performance gain - in particular with an index combining the two columns checked (depending on the actual data distribution). - You have (according to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82324/discussion-between-kamal-pal-and-stack)) the +100,000 of rows of real data to check against...  ;-)

Please comment if and as adjustment / further detail is required.